# Getting or generating Typescript types for REST api

Tags: typescript, rest, type-safety

I am consuming webhooks from and making REST requests to a server. How can I get the typescript types for the data I get from the server? With graphql there are some libraries which can automatically generate types - does something equivalent exist for REST?

Comment: If they have some kind of formatted documentation like GraphQL or Swagger there are some tools dedicated for them to generate types. Otherwise you need to read docs and type them manually.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried it, but give this a look: https://github.com/drwpow/openapi-typescript